# content.select() not working on a <code> element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button to select the contents of a `<code>` element. However, it's not working and I am getting "`content.select()` is not a function

```html
<body>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="copyButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copyConfig()">Copy Config</button>
    <br><br>
    <pre><code id="contentCfg">{{ content }}</code></pre>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    function copyConfig() {
        const content = document.getElementById("contentCfg").textContent;
        content.select();
        content.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
    }
</script>
```

No idea why this wouldn't work, `{{ content }}` automatically gets filled with text by my template serve.r

Comment: `textContent` is a `string` value, not an `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually solve this using [`Document.createRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange), [`Range.selectNodeContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents) and  [`Window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) thus avoiding unnecessary DOM manipulation.

See the [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents#Example) or discussion in this question: [Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

```js
function copyConfig() {
  const contentNode = document.getElementById("contentCfg")

  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(contentNode);
  
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);

  document.execCommand("copy");
}

const copyButton = document.getElementById('copyButton');
copyButton.addEventListener('click', copyConfig);
```

```html
<div>
    <button type="button" id="copyButton" class="btn btn-primary">Copy Config</button>
    <br><br>
    <pre><code id="contentCfg">{{ content }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it by changing the js to this (added the elem parts)

```
function copyConfig() {
        const content = document.getElementById("contentCfg").textContent;
        const elem = document.createElement("textarea");
        document.body.appendChild(elem)
        elem.value = content;
        elem.select();
        elem.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }
```

Comment: You anwered your own question in less than 10 minutes? Bravo.