# How to Copy text from paragraph on webpage in custom oncontext right click menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```js
<script>
            
        window.addEventListener("contextmenu",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var contextElement = document.getElementById("context-menu");
      contextElement.style.top = event.offsetY + "px";
      contextElement.style.left = event.offsetX + "px";
      contextElement.classList.add("active");
    });
    window.addEventListener("click",function(){
      document.getElementById("context-menu").classList.remove("active"); 
    });
    </script>
```

```
<body>
    <div id="context-menu">
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-cut"></i> Cut
  </div>
  <div class="item" onclick="document.execCommand('copy');"> 
<i class="fa fa-clone"></i> Copy
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-paste"></i> Paste
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="item" onclick="window.location.reload();"> **the reload command is working nice**
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Reload
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Exit
  </div>
</div>
```

can you help me with I just want the right click menu copy button to work and function  i just want the copy command to work when i click on the copy button in the oncontext menu please help

Comment: see: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @pilchard yeah i saw that i also wanted to know if there was any way i could do it using onclick function?

Comment: Yes, here's an answer copying the content of a single element on click [content.select() not working on a <code> element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65452928/13762301)

Comment: <div class="item" onclick="copyDivToClipboard()">
<i class="fa fa-clone"></i> Copy

Comment: can i do something to copy the text from the para without adding any button tag whatsoever just adding an id in div or maybe onclick

Comment: Your problem is that the click event is clearing the selection before the `copy` command can be executed. Try using `onmousedown` instead.

Comment: thank you i figured it out guys! really thanks for the help!